# Required file tex/generic/elhyphen\grahyph.tex missing from the elhyphen package, and installing never finishes - how to solve this issue?

Tags: miktex, texlive, installing, texmaker, texlive-2018

I installed TeXmaker and TeXLive/TeXStudio and MikTeX in my Windows 10 laptop, and trying to run a LaTeX file from TexLive that runs with no difficulty and with no error on ShareLaTeX/OverLeaf otherwise. But when I go to 'tools' and choose 'build and view' or 'compile' option, I see this dialog box popping up that says:

"**The required file tex/generic/elhyphen\grahyph5.tex is missing, it's a part of the following package elhyphen**". Then it gives me the options for "**The package will be installed for 'remote package repository'**", and that "**The package will be installed for (my name)**".

Guided by intuition, I chose install. *Then absolutely nothing happens!* During this time, it shows that the square right under 'macros' is red, meaning it's compiling, and it gives me the option to stop compiling. When I do stop compiling, it says it can't find the file.

Exactly the same thing happens when I attempt to compile my TeX file using TexMaker, except here I see the ever-rotating blue circle on the TexMaker screen, meaning the computer is doign soemthing or it's stuck.

Could you please help me out with how to solve this issue? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you running here? tagging both miktex and texlive and texlive-2018 is rather confusing. So please explain more explicitly what you are doing and exactly which latex installation you are using. My guess is that you're actually using miktex as texlive does not install in the fly. Thus, have you updated miktex in miktex admin mode **and** miktex user mode? You may need to refresh the package database mually before miktex wants to update. It is in one of the menus of the miktex console

Comment: If you are using MikTeX, it is certainly worth checking the MikTeX console: in particular, check the connection settings and see whether your machine is talking to a repository correctly. (For example, at work we need to route everything through a proxy and nothing will install on-the-fly until that is set up properly.)